# Converting XML to JSON using R

Tags: r, json, xml

Is there a way to convert between XML & JSON in R Studio?

I've looked at XML & RJSONIO packages in R but didn't find a function to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: And the converse, convert JSON to XML - would you know how to do that in R?

Comment: [Related Q&A with better formulated quetion and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46016660/2204410)

Answer (score 15):

You can convert XML to a `list` using the `xmlToList()` function from the [**XML**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=XML) package, and you can convert a `list` to JSON using the `toJSON()` function from the [**RJSONIO**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RJSONIO) package.

Comment: And the converse, convert JSON to XML - would you know how to do that in R?

Comment: @TomWenseleers That would be: `mylist = RJSONIO::fromJSON("myfile.json")` and `myxml = xml2::as_xml_document(mylist)`

Comment: @Ömer An Thanks a lot for that!