# XML convert to JSON R

Tags: json, r, xml

The packages in R doesn't seem to work properly in conversion of XML to JSON. I've tried RJSONIO, rjson and jsonlite with 'XML' package. I first parsed the XML and convert it into list using XML::xmlToList() and convert them to JSON using toJSON() from those 3 packages.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<votes>
  <row Id="1" PostId="1" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="2" PostId="1" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="3" PostId="3" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
</votes>
```

My source code:

```
library(XML)
library(RJSONIO)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)

xml_parse <- xmlTreeParse("~/Downloads/test.xml", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
xml_root <- xmlRoot(xml_parse)
xml_list <- xmlToList(xml_root, simplify = TRUE)

#jsonlite package
xml_jsonlite <- jsonlite::toJSON(xml_list)
write(xml_jsonlite, "test_jsonlite.json")

#RJSONIO package
xml_rjsonio <- RJSONIO::toJSON(xml_list)
write(xml_rjsonio, "test_rjsonio.json")

#rjson package
xml_rjson <- RJSONIO::toJSON(xml_list)
write(xml_rjson, "test_rjson.json")
```

Converted JSON file from RJSONIO:

```
{
"row": {
    "Id": "98",
    "PostId": "10",
    "VoteTypeId": "2",
    "CreationDate": "2014-05-14T00:00:00.000" 
 },
"row": {
    "Id": "99",
    "PostId": "7",
    "VoteTypeId": "5",
    "UserId": "111",
    "CreationDate": "2014-05-14T00:00:00.000" 
 }
}
```

Which is clearly wrong because of duplicate field name.

Converted JSON file from jsonlite:

```
{"row":["1","1","2","2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"],
 "row.1":["2","1","2","2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"],
 "row.2":["3","3","2","2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"]}
```

Which is weird because there should be only one field name "row" with array of subdocuments instead of incrementing array of "rows". It doesn't even have field names in it.

Converted JSON file from rjson:

```
{
 "row": {
 "Id": "1",
"PostId": "1",
"VoteTypeId": "2",
"CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" 
},
"row": {
 "Id": "2",
"PostId": "1",
"VoteTypeId": "2",
"CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" 
}
}
```

The ideal JSON file would be as such:

```
{"votes" : {
    "row" : [
        {
            "Id" : "1",
            "PostId" : "1",
            "VoteTypeId" : "2",
            "CreationDate" : "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "Id" : "2",
            "PostId" : "1",
            "VoteTypeId" : "2",
            "CreationDate" : "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
        }
       ]
      }
}
```

Looking for solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code you used to get the wrong JSON string as well as the data coming out of your XML conversion so we can help you figure it out properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`xml2` and `jsonlite` get you most of the way there but you haven't even shown us you know R code let alone have really attempted a solution for this, so here's a partial solution posted so it can help others:

```
library(xml2)
library(jsonlite)

read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<votes>
  <row Id="1" PostId="1" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="2" PostId="1" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="3" PostId="3" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2014-05-13T00:00:00.000" />
</votes>') -> doc

x <- xml2::as_list(doc) 

xl <- lapply(x, attributes)

toJSON(xl, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
## {
##   "row": {
##     "Id": "1",
##     "PostId": "1",
##     "VoteTypeId": "2",
##     "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##   },
##   "row.1": {
##     "Id": "2",
##     "PostId": "1",
##     "VoteTypeId": "2",
##     "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##   },
##   "row.2": {
##     "Id": "3",
##     "PostId": "3",
##     "VoteTypeId": "2",
##     "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##   }
## }
```

**Per your comment**

What you want isn't how the data is structured. Which means if you want something, you can't use canned, vanilla utilities.

```
xml_find_all(doc, "//votes/row") %>% 
  map_chr(~{
    toJSON(as.list(xml_attrs(.x)), auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
  }) %>% 
  paste0(collapse=",\n") %>% 
  gsub("[\n]", "\n    ", .) %>% 
  sprintf('{ "votes" : {\n  row" : [\n    %s]\n  }\n}', .) %>% 
  cat()

## { "votes" : {
##   row" : [
##     {
##       "Id": "1",
##       "PostId": "1",
##       "VoteTypeId": "2",
##       "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##     },
##     {
##       "Id": "2",
##       "PostId": "1",
##       "VoteTypeId": "2",
##       "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##     },
##     {
##       "Id": "3",
##       "PostId": "3",
##       "VoteTypeId": "2",
##       "CreationDate": "2014-05-13T00:00:00.000"
##     }]
##   }
## }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @hrbrmstr. I have already tried jsonlite like I said in my post and the output is not really ideal as you can see here, the ideal output would be one field name "row" which contains array of sub-documents instead of multiple incrementing "row" in a single documents.